# Can vmWare Server be installed in a X-less host?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, virtualization, vmware-server

I am planning to move my vmWare's Virtual Machines from a Windows host to a Linux host (Ubuntu). It is possible to run vmWare Server in a Linux host that does not have the graphical environment (does not have X)?

I just wonder how the graphical setup of Windows/Linux guest work in this case.

Thanks in advance for your time.

Victor Marquez

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just install it on Ubuntu Server and install it via apt-get.  Here's a good walkthrough

http://users.piuha.net/martti/comp/ubuntu/en/server.html

I did this on my development server and connect to it using the graphical client on my Windows machine.  I have no gui installed.

Answer (score 1):

the X libraries are required during the compilation and installation of VMware Server on Linux.

Comment: Only the libraries need to be installed, you don't need to have the full X gui running.

Answer (score 1):

[virtualbox](http://www.virtualbox.org/) has some command line tools that you can use and I don't believe it requires an x installation.  You should compare the features and make sure that's what you want though.

Comment: Thanks Jason! I need to find some time in the future to try virtualbox. In a quick visit to their page seems very interesting and fine product. For now, and because of lack of time, I will try craigmoliver's reccomendation.